# How to get graph from sigmajs to display in html page

Tags: aurelia

I am new to Aurelia and have some background in javascript. I am using CLI to build and run my project. Dwayne Charrington has guided me on the integration of sigmajs into Aurelia. Thanks, Dwayne!

I have installed sigma into the project through

```
npm install sigma --save
```

I have prepended the sigma.min.js to aurelia_project/aurelia.json.

```
  "prepend": [
        "node_modules/bluebird/js/browser/bluebird.core.js",
        "node_modules/requirejs/require.js", 
    "node_modules/sigma/build/sigma.min.js"
    ]
```

I am using the attached() lifecycle method to get the ts and html to work together for integrating sigmajs as suggested by Dwayne.

```
-- sigmajs.html
<template>
  <require from="./sigmajs.css"></require>
  <section>
   <div class="col-lg-4 col-lg-offset-4">
     <h1> An </h1>
     <div id="container1"></div>
   </div>
   <div class="col-lg-4 col-lg-offset-4">
    <button click.delegate="refreshUI()"> Refresh UI </button>
   </div>
 </section>
</template>

--sigmajs.ts

export class Sigmajs {
    s;
    refreshUI() {
      this.s.refresh();
      this.s.graph.nodes().forEach(function(n) {
        console.log(n);
      });
    }


    attached() {
      this.s =     new sigma({
        container: 'container1'
      });

      this.s.graph.addNode({
        id: 'n0',
        label: 'Hello',
        x: 10,
        y: 10,
        size: 1,
        color: '#f00'
      }).addNode({
        id: 'n1',
        label: 'World !',
        x: 100,
        y: 10,
        size: 1,
        color: '#00f'
      }).addEdge({
        id: 'e0',
        source: 'n0',
        target: 'n1'
      });
    }
 }

 -- sigmajs.css
 <style>
   #container1 {
   top: 0;
   bottom: 0;
   left: 0;
   right: 0;
   position: absolute;
  }
</style>
```

**I am unable to see the graph on the HTML page**; even when I click the Refresh UI button. When I click the Refresh UI button, I do see the debug statements in the console corresponding to console.log(n) as

```
Object { label: "Hello", x: 10, y: 10, size: 1, color: "#f00", id: "n0", read_cam0:size: 8, read_cam0:x: -2.8125, read_cam0:y: 0, cam0:x: 195.1875, 2 more… }  app-bundle.js:396:17
Object { label: "World !", x: 100, y: 10, size: 1, color: "#00f", id: "n1", read_cam0:size: 8, read_cam0:x: 2.8125, read_cam0:y: 0, cam0:x: 200.8125, 2 more… }  app-bundle.js:396:17
```

thereby leading me to conclude that I am initializing sigmajs correctly; just not seeing the output (of a graph) on HTML

Thank you in advance for your advice.

Comment: When you use the prepend option in `aurelia.json`, I thought you also needd to import the module in your viewmodel.  Something like this: `import sigma from "node_modules/sigma/build/sigma.min.js";` However, if your console log is giving that output, it seems you're probably already working.  Something to try, anyway.

Answer (score 0):

Answering my own question 
The issue was with the css NOT specifying the appropriate height, width with bootstrap also in picture. The following declaration in sigmajs.css shows the rather simple graph (2 nodes, one edge).

```
<style type="text/css">
   body {
     margin: 0;
   } 

   #container2 {
      position: absolute;
      width: 100%;
      height: 100%;
  }
 </style>
```

I am not a CSS guy; so this answer, while it works, may need some nuances for the graph to look better.

@LStarky  It does not seem necessary to do sigma import. I believe that vendor-bundle.js also has sigma due to prepend

Comment: Just saw this, glad you sorted it out. The prepend section is specifically for those times when the dependency you're working with uses the old script tag in page approach.